# Can I get more than one "popular tweet"

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to retrieve several "popular" tweets by using Twitter Search API, but when I try this with "result_type = popular", I basically end up with one "popular" tweet.  Is there anyway I could get tweak the code so I can get more "popular" tweets?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a known issue. It has been previously reported [here](https://dev.twitter.com/issues/199), among a few other issue list.

I am assuming you are doing something like this:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=your_query_string&result_type=popular
```

A limited workaround would be to query for result_type=mixed [or recent], which will return [upto max 3 in case of mixed] popular tweets and then in the result set, filter by the meta field 'result_type'.